# How to get adapter notified when state changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my main activity I have two fragments. One is song list and second is favorite. This both fragment contain ListView and custom adapter. There is a bottom sheet which contain a button . when that button will be clicked that song will be added to favorite(second fragment). I am able to add the song into fragment favorite but it do not show at a time when we add it. we have to restart the application to get it into the favorite. The button to add favorite is operated from main activity . Is there any way that i can notify my adapter that state have been changed.(songs added to favorite use database)

Is there any way i can refresh fragment when it is opened???

This is code of main activity in which favorite is button that adds song name in database when it is clicked.

```
favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(x==0) {                         
  favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);x=1;
                    boolean isinserted =   
  mydb.insertdata(collections.get(a).getsong().toString());

                    if (isinserted == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added as favorite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        x=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                else{favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                    int deletedrow = mydb.deleteData(collections.get(a).getsong());
                    if(deletedrow>0){Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "removed from favorite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());

                        x=0;
                    }
                    else {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " not removed from favorite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from your adapter like this:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

update the list with the newly added item and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this into item click to add into list :

```
    public Both[] boths;
public ArrayList<Both> both = new ArrayList<Both>();
```

onItemClick:

```
String itemValue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(i);
 if (boths == null) {
                boths = new Both[]{    \\Both is your Object Class name
                        new Both(itemValue)  
                };
            }
            both.addAll(Arrays.asList(boths));
            adapters.notifyDataSetChanged();   \\adapters is your Adapter Name 
            adapters.setAdapter(both);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know,  you have two fragments. Here is a solution as follow:

Step 1:
You can define two method to update your adapter in your two fragment!

```
SongFragment:

public void updateDataList(){
    if(songAdapter != null){
        songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

FavoriteFragment:

public void updateDataList(){
    if(favoriteAdapter != null){
        favoriteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Step 2: 
    When your want to update your views, and your MainActivity must hold the SongFragment And FavoriteFragment Instance.
    you can call the method updateDataList in MainActivity. eg:

```
songFragment.updateDataList();
favoriteFragment.updateDataList();
```

Comment: Only when your data list must be changed in your adapter,  it can work!!!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update your fragment if you are retrieving data from database,you need to update your cursor or list, you can check this on fragment in this method or you can make listener where you can listen your added fav event.

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {

        }else{
            // fragment is no longer visible
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it if anybody wants it.

I have used broadcast when button gets clicked. Then that broadcast will be recieved in fragment. In reciever i have cleared the list and then again added the list . Now adapter is notified if state have been changed